# Regex to allow hypen & number only

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using the RegEx `^[0-9]+$"` to allow only digits.
I want to allow hyphens `-` & spaces also.

Can any one help me to modify the RegEx to a proper one?

I was using following JS code to achieve the same, but in this way if the user is copying & pasting the text then the key press is not getting accounted.

```
//Allowed characters are : 8 = Back space,
//9 = Horizontal tab, 27 = esc, 127 = Delete,
//13 = Enter digits = 48 to 57, 45 = hypen

$('#PostalCode').keypress(function (e) {
    var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    return (key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 127 || key == 27 || key == 13 || key == 45 || (key >= 48 && key <= 57));
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add a `-` and space in the character class like so:

```
^[0-9 -]+$
```

Be sure to put the `-` either in the back or front (as it won't be mistaken for a range, then), or escape it:

```
^[0-9 \-]+$
```

You could also use `\d` instead of `0-9`, as they're equivalent:

```
^[\d -]+$
```

Comment: Updated the question, to allow space also.

Comment: @Biki: My regex handles that.

Comment: what is the need of escape character `\ ` before `-`

Comment: @diEcho: I did remove the downvote once you changed the grouping to a character class. :)

Comment: Do I need to use escape sequence for hypen i.e. ^[0-9\- ]+$ instead of ^[0-9- ]+$ ?

Comment: @Biki: It's up to you, really. (Though, the hyphen should be either in front or at the back if not escaped, since the parser won't mistake it for a range, then. I just updated my answer to reflect this.)

Answer (score 1):

use `^[\d-\s]+$` to allow hyphens also

Comment: Updated the question, to allow space also.

Comment: -1: Your regex only match strings of alternating digits and hyphens, and requires length of string to be a multiple of 2. Also, doesn't match spaces.

Comment: @diEcho : Do I need to use escape sequence for hypen i.e. ^[0-9\- ]+$ instead of ^[0-9- ]+$ ?

Comment: @bik NO need of escape sequence for `-` as you can see in my answer.